# Trying to update the global value from a hooked function in PHP

Tags: php

I want to hook into a specific place, and one thing I want to do there is to update a global variable.

In my main PHP file, I have just put the variable

```
$xyz;
```

In a functions file, I have put it.

```
function save_xyz( $user_id ){

  global $xyz;

  if( !xyz ){
    $xyz = 1;
    return $xyz;
  }

  $xyz = 2;
  return $xyz;

}

add_action( "pmpro_after_checkout", "save_xyz" );
```

Theoretically, it should work. anyone help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, using global variables means that there is a logic problem in your script: in your script you are returning a global variable, which makes no sense.

```
<?php

$xyz = 0;

function change_it ($variable) {
  $variable++;
  return $variable;
}

$xyz = change_it($xyz);
```

There are cases for using global variables, but very rarely, as the above code shows, it's quite simple to change a variable without having to use a global one.